# How do I tackle a StackOverflowError when I use this. keyword

Tags: java

I have base class `Triangle` with 3 derived classes `Perimetert` , `Areat` and `heightt` with `main` method named `main1` , `main2` and `main3` respectively.
I am asking the user what operation to perform in the base class. If the user enters 1 the inherited class `Perimetert` should be invoked, 2 then `Areat` and so on.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Triangle
{
public void main1()
{
    this.main1();
}
public void main2()
{
    this.main2();
}
public void main3()
{
    this.main3();
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
    int M , a , b , c , z , y , A , B , C;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Press 1 to find the perimeter\nPress 2 to find the area\nPress 3 to find the missing height");
    M = in.nextInt();
    Triangle ob = new Triangle();
    switch(M)
    {
        case 1:
        ob.main1();
        break;
        case 2:
        ob.main2();
        break;
        case 3:
        ob.main3();
        break;
        default:
        System.out.println("Sorry, I can only do 3 operations.\nThank You!!!!!");
       }
    }
}
```

Can someone please correct this code.

Comment: `main3()` unconditionally calls itself, so you'll have to give it a condition where it stops calling itself and just returns. Actually I don't see why you have each function calling the following one since they all seem to have to do something different.

Comment: Also, as a general suggestion `int M , a , b , c , z , y , A , B , C;` and `main1(), main2(), main3()` you should choose names which are a bit more self-describing.

Comment: What i deduce from your example, you are trying to call subcall methods (premeter, area, height) from Base class method. Inheritance doesn't work this way. You can get super class implementation form subclasses, but not vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with code like this:

```
public void main1()
{
    this.main1();
}
```

is that it creates endless loops.

```
public void main1() // line 1
{
    this.main1(); // line 2
}
```

line 1 is called (by an external method), it triggers line 2, which calls line 1, which triggers line 2, which calls line 1, ...

So, yes, this is bound to lead to problems. If you want to use recursive methods (methods calling themselves), make sure there is always the possibility for them to end

```
int counter = 0;
public void main1()
{
    counter += 1;
    if ( counter < 5 )
        this.main1();
}
```

Comment: How the program should work is like : When i run class Triangle, it should ask which operation to perform and then _directly_ run the derived class concerned.If i enter 1 , the perimeter class should automatically start running. Can that happen ?

Comment: that is a design doomed to fail. you shouldn't "run" derived classes from within a parent class. the parent class shouldn't even be aware the derived classes exist. but your description has nothing to do with the code you've posted. How long have you studied OO programming concepts?